# Sidebar and header are not rendered properly on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9

I have a 2 column layout page with a sidebar and a grid.

The sidebar contains filters and when the user clicks a filter, an ajax request is made and the grid is updated with the new data (only the grid is recreated).

Everything works perfect on all browsers but on IE9 every time the user clicks a filter the sidebar and the header are not rendered properly (the header disappears and the side bar is partially visible).

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

I found that resizing the window helps so I wrote a js function that resizes the window every time the user filters on IE9:

```
var isResized = false;
//Solves a bug with IE rendering where the header dissappears after filtering 
function resizeWindow(){    
    if ( $.browser.msie)
    {
        isResized = true;
        window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth,window.outerHeight - 10); 
    }
}

//Solves a bug with IE rendering where the header dissappears after filtering
$(window).resize(function(){
    try{
        //this will only be true if the resize was made by the script, if a user resized
        //the browser this would e false and nothing will happen
        if(isResized){
            isResized = false;
            window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth,window.outerHeight + 10); 
        }
    }
    catch(err){}
});
```

The problem is that it sometimes work and sometimes not. Is there a better way? Is it possible to re-render a page with JS?

**Sidebar HTML Fragment:**

```
<section>
                <div id ="mySelections" class="selection">
                    <h3>
                        <label I18N="MY_SELECTION"></label>
                        <span></span>
                    </h3>
                    <a href="#" id="clearAll" data-role="button" data-theme="g" I18N="CLEAR_ALL"></a>
                    <ul id="filterList">
                        <li class="status">
                        </li>
                        <li class="serviceFilter">

                        </li>
                        <li class="favorites">

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end .status -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .selection -->
                <div class="contractsSummary">
                    <h3 I18N="CONTRACTS_LIST_SERVICES_TITLE"></h3>
                    <div id="status" data-type="int" data-operator="eq" >
                        <p id ="red" class="filter">
                            <label data-color="red" data-col="ServiceComplianceCurrentPeriod/Severity" data-val="1" I18N="STATUS_RED"></label>
                            <span class="circle red"></span>
                            <span class="quantity"></span>
                            <span class="percentage" ></span>
                        </p>
                        <p id = "yellow" class="filter">
                            <label data-color="yellow" data-col="ServiceComplianceCurrentPeriod/Severity" data-val="2" I18N="STATUS_YELLOW"></label>
                            <span class="circle yellow"></span>
                            <span class="quantity"></span>
                            <span class="percentage"></span>
                        </p>
                        <p id="green" class="filter">
                            <label data-color="green" data-col="ServiceComplianceCurrentPeriod/Severity" data-val="3" I18N="STATUS_GREEN"></label>
                            <span class="circle green"></span>
                            <span class="quantity"></span>
                            <span class="percentage"></span>
                        </p>
                        <!--<p id="all" class="filter">
                            <label data-color="" data-col="" data-val="" I18N="ALL"></label>
                            <span></span>
                        </p>-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end #status -->
                    <div id="favorites" data-type="favorite" data-operator="eq">
                        <p class="filter">
                            <label data-num="" data-col="Id" I18N="FAVORITES"></label>
                            <span></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end .contractsSummary -->
                <div class="filters">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="textFilter" id="serviceFilter" data-col="Name" data-type="string" data-operator="eq" data-text="COLUMN_HEADER_SERVICE"> 
                                <input placeholder="" data-type="search" class="filter" value="" I18N="FILTER_ITEMS" id="service-search"/>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end #textFilter -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- end .filters -->
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :)

All i needed to do was to hide it and then show it again:

```
$('section').hide();
$('section').show();
```